# Extra quotes doing SQL insert from Perl to CSV. If I try to remove them, I get no quotes. I need single quotes as in "0123"

Tags: sql, csv, perl

When I write to a csv file from Perl using SQL Insert, I get either `0123` or `"""0123"""`, but I need `"0123"`.  Neither concatenation nor regex seem to resolve the issue.

Here's my code:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(qq{DBI:CSV:csv_eol=\n;csv_sep_char=\\,;});   
$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'Table'} = {'file' => 'data.csv','col_names' => 
["num","id"]};
#Setup error variables
$dbh->{'RaiseError'} = 1;
$@ = '';

## Attempts to change $num
##$num = '"'.$num.'"';## this causes """0123""" 
##$num = "\"$num\"";## this causes """0123""" even if I additionally do this: 
## $num=~s/"""/"/g;
##$num = " ".$num;## causes " 0123" VERY CLOSE.  Try next line: 
##$num=~s/ //g;## This causes 0123
##$num = "".$num; ## causes 0123
##$num = "'".$num."'";## causes 123

my $value = "\'$num\',\'$id\'";
my $insert = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES ($value)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($insert);
$sth->execute();
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

I would like to have the output of $num to end up being "0123" in the CSV, but instead I get 0123 or """0123""" or " 0123"

Comment: The quotes in the title of your question are double quotes, not single quotes. They also look like you wrote them with Word.

Comment: Bound parameters are supported by DBD::CSV, have you tried it? `VALUES (?,?)` then pass `$num` and `$id` to the execute call.

Comment: Corssposted to [PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11107315)

Comment: choroba, Thank you!! My crosspost to PerlMonks at https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11107315 has the solution! I had to add <code>'always_quote'=> 1</code> to the dbh to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to poj at PerlMonks (https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11107315), there is a solution:

Here it is for everyone's convenience:

Use placeholders and always_quote option

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:CSV:", "", "",{
   'RaiseError' => 1 }
);  

$dbh->{'csv_tables'}->{'MyTable'} = {
 'file'         => 'data1.csv',
 'col_names'    => ["num","id"],
 'always_quote' => 1,
};

my $num = '0123';
my $id  = '0124';
my $sql = "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (?,?)";
my $sth = $dbh->do($sql,undef,$num,$id);
```

poj

Answer (score 3):

Interpolating variables into SQL statements is a bad idea. You leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks (see [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/)). So don't do that.

Instead, use bind parameters and pass extra values to the `execute()` method.

```
my $insert = 'INSERT INTO Table VALUES (?, ?)';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($insert);
$sth->execute($num, $id);
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't solve my initial problem. I need the output to show up in the CSV like this:
<code>"0123"</code>

Comment: @James: As Grinnz says in his other answer, it sounds like the other application is at fault here. In a CSV file, there is no meaningful difference between `0123` and `"0123"`.

Comment: @James: But perhaps you could post-process the CSV file in some way.

Comment: Yes, the other app is at fault, but I have not control over it.  I thought about post-process and even tried an update to CSV, but ran into issues.  However, this quote from https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11107315 shows the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a CSV entry of 123 and of "123" are identical. A single pair of double quotes is part of the CSV format (at least, the most common variant). So when you try to insert a value containing double quotes, it doubles them up to escape them. DBD::CSV is only surrounding the cell in double quotes when it contains special characters like a comma, space, or escaped double quotes.

```
foo," foo ",",","""a""b"
# parses to: 'foo' -- ' foo ' -- ',' -- '"a"b'
```

The parser should not care whether the cell is quoted or not (unless it is needed because the cell contains these special characters). See http://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/

Comment: The cell needs to be quoted due to the use of it by another system that requires it.